# fatal: pathspec for removing folder in git

Tags: git

I want to remove a folder from a Git repository but I get an error.

I tried several commands, and here you can see my errors:

```
selnaz:iOS Lnaz$ ls
iOS-Tidinfo mockup      readme.txt
selnaz:iOS Lnaz$ git rm -r -- iOS-Tidinfo/
fatal: pathspec 'tidinfo/iOS/iOS-Tidinfo/' did not match any files
selnaz:iOS Lnaz$ git rm -r iOS-Tidinfo/
fatal: pathspec 'tidinfo/iOS/iOS-Tidinfo/' did not match any files
selnaz:iOS Lnaz$ git rm -r iOS-Tidinfo/
fatal: pathspec 'tidinfo/iOS/iOS-Tidinfo/' did not match any files
selnaz:iOS Lnaz$ git rm -r tidinfo/iOS/iOS-Tidinfo/
fatal: pathspec 'tidinfo/iOS/tidinfo/iOS/iOS-Tidinfo/' did not match any files
```

**Edit**

```
selnaz:iOS Lnaz$ rm -r iOS-Tidinfo
override r--r--r--  
Lnaz/staff for iOS-Tidinfo/.git/objects/00/ae692a7725dfb4af05e3051a8c3ba78b7f0706? ls
rm: 
iOS-Tidinfo/.git/objects/00: Directory not empty
override r--r--r--  Lnaz/staff for 
 iOS-  Tidinfo/.git/objects/01/6bdb82585a4b0660f0da5ee8e0a3fef8474073?
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove a folder in Git, as you cannot add one.

Git can only manage files. So, to remove a folder you will have to remove every file inside that folder:

```
git rm iOS-Tidinfo/* ; git commit -a
```

If the folder is empty or all the files inside are not tracked by Git you can simply remove the folder with:

```
rm -r iOS-Tidinfo
```

Comment: when I add you comment I got this selnaz:iOS Lnaz$ rm -r iOS-Tidinfo
override r--r--r--  Lnaz/staff for iOS-Tidinfo/.git/objects/00/ae692a7725dfb4af05e3051a8c3ba78b7f0706? ls
rm: iOS-Tidinfo/.git/objects/00: Directory not empty
override r--r--r--  Lnaz/staff for iOS-Tidinfo/.git/objects/01/6bdb82585a4b0660f0da5ee8e0a3fef8474073?

Comment: @ElnazShahmehr: Please state in your question what is the git directory root folder and what is the folder you want to remove. Considering the output you just provided you are trying to remove your repository root folder.

Comment: I have all this folders timereportingtools/tidinfo/iOS/iOS-Tidinfo/ my git repository is timereportingtools/ and I want to remove iOS-Tidinfo/ folder

Comment: @ElnazShahmehr: Your last edit shows that you have a .git folder inside the iOS-Tidinfo, what is not supposed since you should only have a .git folder inside your root repository folder. If you don't have uncommited changes I recomend you to clean your working directory with `git clean -df`, or clone the repository again.

Comment: thannks for your reply , git clean -df didn't work I think I should clone it again!